# How to apply weights in building decision tree?

Tags: cart, adaboost

Hi I'm currently trying to implement Adaboost algorithm. I have implemented the weak classifier using decision tree (instead of using the fit function provided by sklearn). However, I had a tough time applying the weights on the data points to the tree building process. I have a tuition that the weights would have to be used in gini index,  but I don't particularly know how to do that. Could someone shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: I think you meant intuition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AdaBoostM1 reweighting examples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330367/adaboostm1-reweighting-examples)