# AdaBoostM1 reweighting examples

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, boosting, adaboost

[image]

It is said Adaboost increases the weights of the misclassified examples. But if I look at step 2(b) , err is between 0 and 1. Then at step 2(c) , If err=1 , alpha = log(0)=-inf and if err=0, alpha = log(inf) = inf, Now in 2(d) we multiply weights by e^alpha for misclassified examples. If alpha = -inf then these misclassified examples are actually downweighted by the bad classfier , instead of being upweighted.

I thought that all misclassified points should be upweighted, and the upweighting should be more for a good classifier than a wrong one.

Could someone please explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought more about it and got the answer. There is an assumption in AdaBoost that all classifiers are slightly better than average so err < 1/2

Using that alpha >=0 , which makes everything fine :)